# How to implement quick launch options in android notification panel for our own applications like paytm?

Tags: android

I would like to implement my own custom quick launch notification panel like paytm 
[image]

Can anyone just provide me a reference for the same?

Comment: that is just a custom notification. Just search for how to create custom notifications.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  how does it run even if the app is not running ?? is this some background service running just for this custom notification??

Comment: `is this some background service` who knows? If you want to know that, you should ask the guys who developed that app, not us. Or you should explain what you want in words, not using *like they did in their app*